# How to show the terminal associated with a window in the status line

Tags: terminal, tmux

I tend to have a workflow with many terminal windows on my screen all running tmux with various different things running in them.  I often find myself wanting to know "where is this background process running?"  I can easily find the tty name it is running on (ps shows it), but figuring out which window to look at is very hard.

My obvious thought was "Let's use the tmux status line to display this!".  So I tried the command

```
set-option -g window-status-format "#(tty):#W#F"
```

but unfortunately, this just seems to display `not a tty` in the status line instead of the tty for the window.  Is there any good way to get this to display the tty name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tmux is a terminal multiplexer. Your tmux server provides ttys to processes running "inside" tmux, in panes (note: a tmux window not split into panes is just one big tmux pane). Tmux clients use ttys usually provided by terminal emulators or virtual terminals. The processes use their respective ttys, the tmux server manages data flow and ultimately you see windows, panes and a status line displayed by your tmux client in its tty.

The tmux server itself is not attached to any tty though. The server is responsible for refreshing the status line. Your tmux server was invoking the `tty` command you specified and got `not a tty` each time.

It seems you want to know ttys of panes, not the tty the tmux client uses. Try the following tmux command:

```
set-option -g window-status-format "#{pane_tty}:#W#F"
```

Notes:

- There is also [`window-status-current-format`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#window-status-current-format). You probably want to modify it as well.
- Each entry in the window list in the status line is associated with a tmux window. Tmux windows are not directly associated to ttys. A window is a set of panes plus their layout. Any tmux window can be split into two or more panes. `#{pane_tty}` in our format will show you the tty of the most recently used pane in the respective window. Your whole idea will work really well only if each of your tmux windows is one big pane.

Comment: Thanks this works great for the case where each window has only one pane (which is what I usually do -- if I want to split the screen, I usually just create multiple terminal windows and run a tmux "client" in each one, with mulitple single-pane windows.)  Maybe would be nice if there was a way of getting all the ttys for the panes in a window.

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated above, you can try using the pane_tty format variable in the window status format to display the tty name for the active pane of the window. This is an example command that sets the window status format with the pane_tty variable:

```
set-option -g window-status-format "#(pane_tty): #W#F"
```

This will display the tty name followed by the window name and any flags (if present) in the status line. You can customize the format as per your preferences.

Note that this will only display the tty name for the active pane in the window. If you have multiple panes running different processes with different ttys, you'll need to switch to each pane to see the tty name in the status line.